# Appends and returns items from list object into string array from list of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have models like below:

```
public class Rhistory
{      
     public User User { get; set; }    
}

public class Vhistory
{      
     public User User { get; set; }    
}

public class User
{
     public string UserId { get; set; }
}

public class Info
{
     public List<Rhistory> Rhistory { get; set; }
     public List<Vhistory> Vhistory { get; set; }
}
```

I have `List<Info>` that contains `List<Rhistory>` and `List<Vhistory>`
From `List<Info>` I want to fetch all `UserId` into new `string[]`, that are present in `List<Rhistory>` user object and `List<Vhistory>` user object.

I am doing something like below:

```
        string[] rHistoryUserIds = Info
                           .Where(u => !Equals(u.Rhistory, null))
                           .SelectMany(v => v.Rhistory)
                           .Select(c => new string[] { c.User.UserId })
                           .SelectMany(m => m)
                           .Distinct().Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();

        string[] vHistoryUserIds = Info
                           .Where(u => !Equals(u.Vhistory, null))
                           .SelectMany(v => v.Vhistory)
                           .Select(c => new string[] { c.User.UserId })
                           .SelectMany(m => m)
                           .Distinct().Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();

        string[] userIds = rHistoryUserIds.Union(vHistoryUserIds).ToArray();
```

Can anyone please suggest me a shorter and faster way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the issue with the existing code?

Comment: So many `SelectMany` and `Select`. One `Rhistory` or `Vhistory` only has one `UserId`. a simple `var rhistoryUsers = infosList.SelectMany(x => x.Rhistory.Select(y => y.User.UserId));`

Comment: @viveknuna I just want to shorten this logic that's all.

Comment: `var vhistoryUserIds = infos.Where(item => item.Vhistory != null).SelectMany(item => item.Rhistory).Select(item => item.User.UserId).Distinct();`

Comment: `var rhistoryUserIds = infos.Where(item => item.Rhistory != null).SelectMany(item => item.Vhistory).Select(item => item.User.UserId).Distinct();`

Comment: Is `Info` a list or single instance?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Its a list object.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly select the subsets of userId in Rhistory and Vhistory into a anonymous class, then use union within select query. Finally use SelectMany to get the userId array.

```cs
//Get your info list into infos
var infos = GetInfos();
var result = infos.Select(x => new
{
    RUserIds = x.Rhistory.Select(a => a?.User.UserId),
    VUserIds = x.Vhistory.Select(a => a?.User.UserId),
}).Select(x => new
{
    UserIds = x.RUserIds.Union(x.VUserIds)
}).SelectMany(x => x.UserIds).Where(x => x != null).ToArray();
```

Comment: Just use `?` operator when you select history user, and exclude null value in the end.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I optimized it thanks to all who gave suggestions.

```
        var rUsers = Info.Where(c => c.Rhistory != null)
                                 .SelectMany(cn => cn.Rhistory)
                                 .Select(users => users?.User?.UserId)
                                 .Where(u => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(u))
                                 .Distinct();

        var vUsers = Info.Where(c => c.Vhistory != null)
                                 .SelectMany(cn => cn.Vhistory)
                                 .Select(users => users?.User?.UserId)
                                 .Where(u => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(u))
                                 .Distinct();


        var userIds = rUsers.Union(vUsers).ToArray();
```